# How do I show that $\text{Sym}^k(V)\oplus\bigwedge^k(V)=V^{\otimes k}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have defined both $\text{Sym}^k(V)$ and $\bigwedge^k(V)$ as quotient space of vector power $V^{\otimes k}$. So how do I understand that $\text{Sym}^k(V)\oplus\bigwedge^k(V)=V^{\otimes k}$, since elements of symmetric and exterior power are equivalence classes?

Comment: That's only true when $k=1,2$; for larger $k$ there are more direct summands. The full decomposition of $V^{\otimes k}$ is $\cong\bigoplus_\lambda{\Bbb S}_\lambda(V)^{m_\lambda}$ where $\lambda\vdash k$ varies over all integer partitions and ${\Bbb S}_\lambda$ represents the Schur functors. See "Schur-Weyl duality." Also, these modules that appear as summands can be understood as quotient spaces, or they may instead be understood as certain invariant subspaces so the equality makes sense as an internal direct sum.

Comment: I am not convinced with the equality: if $k=0$ it is equivalent to $\mathbb K\oplus \mathbb K=\mathbb K$ and for $k=1$ you state that $V\oplus V=V$

Comment: @anon for $k=1$ it cannot work as $V$, $Sym^1(V)$ and $\wedge^{1}(V)$ coincide.

Comment: Can those voting to close please help the OP to improve their question by giving them some feedback?

Comment: @Avitus: Indeed. Though anon's formula in terms Schur functors is correct (at least in char 0). When $k=1$ there is only a single partition of $k$, and hence also only a single summand.

Comment: Anyway, the claim in OP's question is incorrect. For example, when $k=3$ and $\dim V=3$, we have that $\dim Sym^3(V)=10$ and $\dim \bigwedge^3(V)=1$, but $\dim V^{\otimes3}=27\neq 10+1$. No good.

Comment: Ok, I see the statement is right only in case $k=2$. There is no way I can improve this question, should I delete it?

Comment: @haemhweg Of course there is a way to improve the question. Ask about the case $k=2$, and then ask how it generalizes to arbitrary $k$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will be working in characteristic zero algebraically closed base field $K$ exclusively.

Symmetric and exterior powers are understood as quotients of tensor powers, specifically by the ideals generated by the relations $\sigma a=a$ and $\sigma a={\rm sgn}(\sigma)a$ for all $\sigma\in S_n$ respectively. We do have $V^{\otimes 2}=S(V)\oplus T(V)$ though, where $S^2(V)$ and $T^2(V)$ respectively denote the subspaces of symmetric and antisymmetric tensors. We also have isomorphisms

$${\rm Sym}^2(V)\cong S^2(V):vw\mapsto\frac{v\otimes w+w\otimes v}{2},$$
$${\rm Alt}^2(V)\cong T^2(V): v\wedge w\mapsto\frac{v\otimes w-w\otimes v}{2}$$

One can see these (anti-)symmetrization maps generalize to $n$th powers, not just $2$nd ones, and may verify these are indeed isomorphisms by computing dimensions.

The dimension formulas are given by

$$\dim V^{\otimes n}=(\dim V)^n,\quad \dim {\rm Sym}^n(V)=\binom{\dim V+n-1}{n},\quad \dim{\rm Alt}^n(V)=\binom{\dim V}{n}.$$

It is easy to see that $d^n\ne\binom{d+n-1}{n}+\binom{d}{n}$ as polynomials in $d$ unless $n=2$ by checking the leading coefficients of both sides ($1$ vs. $2/n!$), hence this decomposition doesn't work for $V^{\otimes n}$.

But, reviewing the case $n=2$ again, the isomorphism is hardly just one of vector spaces: in fact it is an isomorphism of ${\rm GL}(V)$-$S_n$ bimodules. The actions of ${\rm GL}(V)$ and $S_n$ on $V^{\otimes n}$ are given by

$$\begin{cases} A(v_1\otimes\cdots \otimes v_n)=Av_1\otimes\cdots\otimes Av_n & A\in{\rm GL}(V) \\ (v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n)\sigma=v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma(n)} & \sigma\in S_n\end{cases}$$

Seeing that the $S_n$-action is in fact a right action can be tricky.

The decomposition $V^{\otimes 2}\cong{\rm Sym}^2(V)\oplus{\rm Alt}^2(V)$ generalizes to arbitrary $n$ through a cool piece of work called Schur-Weyl duality, a representation-theoretic theorem. I will recount the highlights.

The irreducible representations of $S_n$ can be constructed explicitly using idempotents called Young symmetrizers $c_\lambda\in K[S_n]$. Both they and the irreps are indexed by integer partitions $\lambda\vdash n$. The left and right Specht modules are given by $S_\lambda^{\rm L}\cong K[S_n]c_\lambda$ and $S_\lambda^{\rm R}\cong c_\lambda K[S_n]$; these are the irreducible representations of $S_n$. The group algebra decomposes as $K[S_n]\cong\bigoplus_\lambda S_\lambda^{\rm L}\otimes_K S_\lambda^{\rm R}$.

(Group algebras decompose this way in general; this is content of the Peter-Weyl theorem.) So

$$\large\begin{array}{ll} V^{\otimes n} & \cong V^{\otimes n}\otimes_{K[S_n\,]}K[S_n] \\
& \cong V^{\otimes n}\otimes_{K[S_n]}\left(\bigoplus_\lambda S_\lambda^{\rm L}\otimes_K S_\lambda^{\rm R}\right) \\
& \cong \bigoplus_\lambda V^{\otimes n}\otimes_{K[S_n]}\left(S_\lambda^{\rm L}\otimes_K S_\lambda^{\rm R}\right) \\
& \cong \bigoplus_\lambda \left(V^{\otimes n}\otimes_{K[S_n]} S_\lambda^{\rm L}\right)\otimes_K S_\lambda^{\rm R} \\
& \cong \bigoplus_\lambda {\Bbb S}_\lambda(V)\otimes_K S_\lambda^{\rm R} \end{array}$$

where ${\Bbb S}_\lambda$ are the Schur functors, given by ${\Bbb S}_\lambda(V)\cong V^{\otimes n}\otimes_{K[S_n]}S_\lambda^{\rm R}\cong V^{\otimes n}c_\lambda$ (one may verify that this construction is in fact functorial). Not only does this ${\rm GL}(V)$-$S_n$ bimodule decomposition hold, the ${\Bbb S}_\lambda(V)$s are the irreducible representations of ${\rm GL}(V)$, and the $K$-spans of ${\rm GL}(V)$ and $S_n$ inside ${\rm End}_K(V^{\otimes n})$ are each other's *full* mutual centralizers.

The symmetric, exterior powers correspond to ${\Bbb S}_\lambda$ with $\lambda=(n)$, $\lambda=(1~\cdots~1)$ respectively, with corresponding Specht modules isomorphic to $K$ with trivial and sign representation respectively.

**Further reading**.

- *Representation Theory: A first course* (Fulton & Harris). Presumably chapters 4 & 6.
- *Young Tableaux and the Representations of the Symmetric Group* (Zhao) [Link](http://www.thehcmr.org/issue2_2/tableaux.pdf).
- *Lie Groups: An Approach through Invariants and Representations* (Procesi). Specifically chapter 9 on tensor symmetry. Draft available online [here](http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/procesi/tensor.pdf).

Comment: Nice answer anon.